# Use for variable as parameter and keep it different for each iteration

Tags: actionscript, parameters, actionscript-2

I have a basic for loop to loop through buttons and set some stuff and onPress handlers:

```
for (i=1;i<=20;i++){
  //do some stuff
  _root["button"+i].onPress = function(){ someMC.gotoAndStop(i+1); }
}
```

However, as I noticed, all buttonsthen link to one and same frame - all point to last `i` + 1 - Is there any possibility to call `gotoAndStop` with "static" `Number`, so in next iteration, it won't change?

Edit: Ex. for last statement:

```
Iteration 5 will call gAS /*gotoAndStop:]*/(6);
Iteration 6 -> gAS(7);
Iteration 7 -> gAS(8);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved it with object properties:

```
for (i=1;i<=20;i++){
  //do some stuff
  _root["button"+i].someproperty = i+1;
  _root["button"+i].onPress = function(){ someMC.gotoAndStop(this.someproperty); }
}
```